# how to access second_view_controller's scroll view from first_view_controller in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, scrollview

For example,,

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

track *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
if([txt1.text isEqualToString:@"scroll"]) {
 transferViewController.trackData = @"Scrolling Part >"; //secondviewcontroller's LABEL
    [transferViewController.scrviw1 setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [transferViewController.scrviw1 setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(280, 800))];
}
else{
   transferViewController.trackData = @"Scroll view Not enabled >"; 
}
}
```

Now,, if v run the code,,, if condition satisfied,, "Scrolling part" label is displayed in next controller,, but scroll view is not displaying.how to access this scroll bar????

Comment: need more details. for what purpose to try this ?

Comment: wat details u need????

Comment: I suggest to do the UI update on the `-viewWillAppear:` of the view controller where the `scrviw1` is residing.

Comment: what the is the need to get the scrollview in first view controller in my another choice u r passing the data from first VC to second VC, u check the data and condition in second VC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

track *transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
if([txt1.text isEqualToString:@"scroll"]) {
 transferViewController.trackData = @"Scrolling Part >"; //secondviewcontroller's LABEL
 [transferViewController view]; // to make sure view is loaded
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [transferViewController.scrviw1 setScrollEnabled:YES];
                [transferViewController.scrviw1 setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(280, 800))];
            });

}
else{
   transferViewController.trackData = @"Scroll view Not enabled >"; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do as below -

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  transferViewController = [segue destinationViewController];   //Make global declaration of track.
  if([txt1.text isEqualToString:@"scroll"]) {
  {
    transferViewController.scrollFlag = YES;   //Create a Bool property as scrollFlag
    //OR
    [transferViewController setScrollWithFlag:@"YES"];   //A method to set scroll of scrollView.

     //Also do what u want to do.
  }
  else
  {
   //Do as u did.
  }
}
```

Similarly create that Bool property (scrollFlag) or implement that setScrollWithFlag method in track controller. And you will be able to set scroll of scrollview.

Anything else pls let me know.